# Unable to post via express using bodyparser

Tags: node.js, postgresql, post, express, body-parser

I have a web app containing four routes out of which two are executing insert query in  Postgresql and two are executing select query. The post in insert is working fine but post in select query is not working. Is this problem of the query or post i'm unable to understand. Printing the post var gives undefined. Please help.

```
ws.post('/prab',function(req,res){
  var vill  =  req.body.addr;
  console.log(vill);
  if(!(vill = null) )
  {
    pg.connect(conString,function(err,client,done){
      if(err){
        return console.error('Could not connect to postgres' , err);
      }
      var results = [];
      var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM \"Area_info\" WHERE \"FOLDER_NAME = $1",[vill],function(err,result){
        console.log(vill);
        console.log(query);
        query.on('row', function(row) {
          results.push(row);
        });
        query.on('end', function() {
          done();
          return res.json(results);
        });
        if(err) {
          return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        else{
          if(results.length == 0)
          {
            res.render('abs');
          }
          else{
            res.render('re');
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't say anything without having a look at your code. Please update your question with your code

Comment: Just did..@SwarajGiri

Comment: Can you show the code from where you are making the request from client side?

Comment: @KethaKavya here...http://pastebin.com/a3R5RRFd

Comment: Modify the input field in the form with this code and try it:    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addr" id="addr" style="width:50%; align:center"placeholder="Enter address separated by slash">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was silly on my part as i picked bootstrap template , i forgot to change the type of button from button to input. Thanks everybody to help me and waste your precious time on my silly mistake. I would be careful from next time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem:

```
if(!(vill = null) )
```

You're doing an assignment to vill and not the equality operator (== or ===). The assignment operator according to the Node REPL returns whatever is on the right hand side which in this case is null. Therefore, the statement (`!(vill=null)`)above will always evaluate to true.

Comment: I removed it but still getting undefined on console.log(vill)

Comment: @J.Alan Interesting. I would put a middleware printing `req.query` or `req.body` out and see what is coming through. In addition to that, I would set the environment variable `DEBUG=*` and then restart the server. This'll enable debug statements from many modules including `body-parser`. It'll give you some clue on what's going on within your express app.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. But req.body gave null array and also debug=* gave nothing interesting